# ActiveMQ queue Encoding

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am sending messages to ActiveMQ queue.

When i send Hebrew letters in the message they dont show correctly, instead "???" is presented.

I am sure its a matter of Encoding.

How can i set the queue Encoding?

Right now i am sending messages encoded as "utf-8" like this:

```
            message = "אבגדהוז";
            TextMessage mes = session.createTextMessage(message);
            System.out.println(mes);
            producer.send(mes);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For special chrecters ActiveMQ encodes as 'utf-16' when sending the message from admin console.

When not sending from console the message should be sent and taken using 'utf-8' encoding.

Comment: Can I configure the ActiveMQ admin console to send as UTF-8 instead of UTF-16?

Comment: I'm curious if ActiveMQ automatically convert (by default) all messages to a specific character encoding.