# ActiveMq sends encoding: sends &#65533;

Tags: encoding, activemq-classic

I am trying to send a message with content: `öäüß€` (german special characters).
In order to debug the content in my receiver, I have implemented:

```
for (int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) {
            char c = content.charAt(i);
            if (c > 255) {
                sb.append("&#");
                sb.append((int) c);
                sb.append(";");
            } else {
                sb.append(c);
            }
        }
```

And every char is: `&#65533;`

Is it a problem of encoding configuration? How could I fix it?
As I read in other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009934/activemq-queue-encoding) by default it should work, but I am running out of ideas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should work.  How are you setting the content?  One thing to try is to put String content = "öäüß€"; just above this piece of code and see if you get the same thing.  The source file should be UTF-8.

Comment: I am sending the content (in testing phase) through the ActiveMQ user interface (Send JMS Message).
In practice, I have two applications running, in the middle of them is ActiveMQ. I am sending Objects from one to another parsed in JSON. I don´t know how I could set any kind of encoding on it...